# Freeswitch not able to run the SampleClient

Tags: .net, voip, freeswitch

I have got hold of the freeswitch sample client for using `Freeswitch.Managed.dll` from [`here`](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Embedding_FreeSWITCH#References).

Just was able to build it properly but when i run it i get:

> The type initializer for 'FreeSWITCH.Native.freeswitch' threw an exception.

on clicking the "Start Freeswitch Core" button.

Any clues?

Comment: did you ever get any help on this?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like there is an error in the DLL. Contact the developers.

Comment: do you have any experience in Freeswitch?